# php two-way encryption for passing variables through URL

Tags: php, url, encryption, get, two-way

OK... to the point...

I have a e-mailshot program that sends out thousands of emails - each with `str_replace()` merge fields (fields that get replaced by a row value in a recordset).

One of the important parts is my ability to track those mails on open so I include a single server-side generated pixel...

```
<img src="http://...trace.php?email=<<<EMAIL>>>" alt="" height="1" width="1">
```

The `str_replace()` replaces `<<<EMAIL>>>` with a unique real email address.

The `trace.php` file reads the `$_GET['email']` and either logs it or sends mail confirmation.

My issue is security :)

I want to use two-way encryption so that the `$_GET` variable sent in the URL is an encrypted email.  The trace.php file then needs to decrypt it.

As it's being sent in a URL, It has to be in ASCII format otherwise it will corrupt before decrypting.

I can't use `openssl_encrypt()` & `openssl_decrypt()` and I'm having to work with php 5.2.0 (don't hurl abuse at me!).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why, instead, don't you generate a token that you can then associate with an email address on the server side?

Comment: Anything that is *encrypted* can be *decrypted* and hence still represents an **attack surface**. Remove any and all attack surfaces entirely by making the values you send *meaningless, random garbage*. You'll just have to store that garbage on your side too.

Comment: I would have to create comparison tokens dynamically to store in the MySQL.  Is this what you mean?  Surely it would be simpler to encrypt the email string?

Comment: @RichardOwens yes, that's what I (and I think @deceze) mean. And no, it wouldn't be that much harder.

Comment: Hash the email, store both hash and email in table.  When trace.php is accesses look up hash and get email.

Comment: Thanks @deceze - good point although I'm trying to work out how I can use one way encryption but still be able to 'find' the relevant record from the database using a hashed variable...  I've only used hashing for comparisons before (passwords etc.)

Comment: Also, no need to hash either just insert email with auto-increment id and use that. Not really security here just obscurity.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think I know what I have to achieve but I still need an ASCII format hashed version to store in the MySQL - can anyone point me in the right direction?  I'll have to run a batch query on this.

Comment: @AbraCadaver surely adding an auto-increment id doesn't really obscure either?

Comment: A simple numeric id is inherently meaningless. Anyone seeing `id=5` inside a URL has absolutely no information about what email that is connected to.

Comment: My email id=1776, what is my email address?

Comment: Good point!!!!  I just need to find that record and echo back the mail address!  Duh....

Comment: No wait... I can't do that.  The trace.php file is hosted externally and the records database is hosted independently on an intranet.  I can't SELECT using the $_GET data :(

Comment: The use of "one way encryption" and "two way encryption" is essentially incorrect. Encryption is reversible by definition. What you are calling "one way encryption" is a cryptographic hash and is not encryption since it can not be reversed.

Comment: @zaph I am familiar with the differences.  Please excuse the way in which I've used the terms.  I have prevously "hashed" passwords etc. but I am looking at "encryption" here. :)

Answer (score 0):

While many of the comments you have received offer other valid ways of solving the problem e.g. a table of email addresses with primary keys, I am of the position that the best way to solve the problem is the way you originally intended: including the email address encrypted in the query URL.

I feel that this way is better because:

- Computing the email address does not require database access.  Database bottle-necking is generally the biggest offender for high-latency requests.
- Encryption means that the same email address will produce a different IV/ciphertext pair each time you encrypt it.  Thus, if you send multiple emails at different times (say, for two different marketing campaigns), the URL will be different each time.  This may not have an effect, but it does provide a security advantage in that an attacker can't "pretend" that an email has been opened simply by visiting a URL.

The issue is that for this way to be better, you have to do it **well**.  I've included an excerpt in PHP from [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) below.  If you can't use `openssl_*` then upgrade your PHP version.  Do not, **ever**, use the `mcrypt_` functions.  They are deprecated **for a reason**.  You may need to hex encode instead of base64 encode the email addresses as is done in the example below.

```
<?php

define("ALGORITHM_NAME", "aes-128-gcm");
define("ALGORITHM_NONCE_SIZE", 12);
define("ALGORITHM_TAG_SIZE", 16);
define("ALGORITHM_KEY_SIZE", 16);
define("PBKDF2_NAME", "sha256");
define("PBKDF2_SALT_SIZE", 16);
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 32767);

function encryptString($plaintext, $password) {
    // Generate a 128-bit salt using a CSPRNG.
    $salt = random_bytes(PBKDF2_SALT_SIZE);
    // Derive a key.
    $key = hash_pbkdf2(PBKDF2_NAME, $password, $salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, ALGORITHM_KEY_SIZE, true);
    // Encrypt and prepend salt and return as base64 string.
    return base64_encode($salt . encrypt($plaintext, $key));
}
function decryptString($base64CiphertextAndNonceAndSalt, $password) {
    // Decode the base64.
    $ciphertextAndNonceAndSalt = base64_decode($base64CiphertextAndNonceAndSalt);
    // Retrieve the salt and ciphertextAndNonce.
    $salt = substr($ciphertextAndNonceAndSalt, 0, PBKDF2_SALT_SIZE);
    $ciphertextAndNonce = substr($ciphertextAndNonceAndSalt, PBKDF2_SALT_SIZE);
    // Derive the key.
    $key = hash_pbkdf2(PBKDF2_NAME, $password, $salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, ALGORITHM_KEY_SIZE, true);
    // Decrypt and return result.
    return decrypt($ciphertextAndNonce, $key);
}
function encrypt($plaintext, $key) {
    // Generate a 96-bit nonce using a CSPRNG.
    $nonce = random_bytes(ALGORITHM_NONCE_SIZE);
    // Encrypt and prepend nonce.
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, ALGORITHM_NAME, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $nonce, $tag);
    return $nonce . $ciphertext . $tag;
}
function decrypt($ciphertextAndNonce, $key) {
    // Retrieve the nonce and ciphertext.
    $nonce = substr($ciphertextAndNonce, 0, ALGORITHM_NONCE_SIZE);
    $ciphertext = substr($ciphertextAndNonce, ALGORITHM_NONCE_SIZE, strlen($ciphertextAndNonce) - ALGORITHM_NONCE_SIZE - ALGORITHM_TAG_SIZE);
    $tag = substr($ciphertextAndNonce, strlen($ciphertextAndNonce) - ALGORITHM_TAG_SIZE);
    // Decrypt and return result.
    return openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, ALGORITHM_NAME, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $nonce, $tag);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort here.  Regrettably, I can't call some pre-defined functions here including random_bytes() or hash_pbkdf2().

Comment: You need to upgrade your version of PHP.  The effort required to implement this without those functions is substantially more than the effort required to just upgrade your PHP version.

Comment: I'm rapidly coming to that conclusion!!  I'm just sorry I can't put your hard work to good use.  Kudos.